# Retrieve old lock screen notifications

Tags: iphone, notifications, touch-id

I pressed the home button on my iPhone 6.  I noticed that there was a notification on the lock screen - something about iCloud.  Before I could read more than a few words, Touch ID helpfully kicked in and unlocked the phone, taking me to my home screen.

I wanted to finish reading it, so I pulled down the notification center from the top and didn't see the message on Today or Notifications.  Is there any way to get such notifications back, or should I develop muscle memory of clicking the home button and quickly removing my thumb from the button to avoid losing these forever?

*edit*: This no longer appears to be a problem in iOS 10.  woot

Comment: Or maybe I could just resort to using a passcode instead of Touch ID to unlock my phone.  Gross.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just swipe down from the top of the locked screen. The old notifications will scroll down.

Comment: Sweet.  This appears to be new (read: restored) as of iOS 10.  Can anyone confirm the version this was added in?

Comment: doesn't work on iOS 12

Answer (score 3):

Apple messed up, in my opinion, by taking away the "missed" tab on the notification pull down in iOS 8.

The only thing I've found that helps is to navigate to settings > notifications and set "sort by time".   After that you can pull down the notification center, and the notifications will still be grouped by app, but at least they are sorted so the most recent **group** is on top, then you can scroll down reading the top notifications out of each group until you get "caught up"

Personally I used that "missed" tab more than almost another screen on the phone, I can't believe they eliminated it.

Comment: Thanks - I will give it a shot.  This sounds like it's probably the best bet.  If it works I'll approve (and upvote).  It does seem like it's a kind of a big oversight.  Hopefully those making the product decisions are 'dogfooding' and will run across the same pain point.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed, but you can also delete notifications either individually or as an entire group from the same app.  Apple may think that's the answer, delete the notifications you have seen.  I'm not a deleter tho, I prefer to be able to go back and read it again, even if it's something simple.  The old way the "missed" tab that has gone missing was sorted was perfect for my style.

Answer (score 2):

Since this seems to be a popular question, I'll post an updated answer for completeness (and to help anyone searching for the answer on newer devices).

## On iOS 11

Let's say you have notifications on the lock screen. You unlocked your device before you had a chance to see them, perhaps because the phone unlocked too quickly, or because you were trying to access an app and didn't have time to check the lock screen notifications.

There is a simple way to see which notifications were on the lock screen again: just pull down the Notification Center from the top of the screen. In it, you'll see the *same exact notifications* which you had on the lock screen. You will keep seeing these notifications in the Notification Center when you pull it down, until you lock your phone. So essentially you can pull the Notification Center down, deal with lock screen notification 1, pull the Notification Center down again, deal with lock screen notification 2, etc.

What if you want to see your previous lock screen notifications, *after* you've locked your device? It's simple: just *swipe up* on either the lock screen or the Notification Center. Then you'll see your past notifications, up to notifications from the past week. It isn't possible to tell which ones are the lock screen notifications that you missed, but you should be able to tell by looking at them – they will be grouped together chronologically.

---

Starting with iOS 11, the lock screen and Notification Center were updated. Now they have been merged, and have a new name: the *Cover Sheet.* When you turn your phone screen on, you'll see a locked Covert Sheet. When you're unlocked and you pull down from the top of the screen, you'll be bringing down the Cover Sheet. However, I used the old terms in my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Train yourself to press the Home button with a different finger. I use my thumb to hit it first, specifically to see notifications. I often swipe one next before using my index finger to unlock the phone. That way I go right to the notifying app.

Comment: This makes it really difficult to use the phone one-handed (my most common use case).  Now, if I had two opposable thumbs on each hand, I could set one up with Touch ID and use the other thumb to wake the phone up. :)

Comment: @jinglesthula if you're using a thumb then you can teach your iphone to recognize some other part of your thumb, like a side of it. as for me, i'm using my pinky for touch id - because I selected a finger that I will miss the least in case of a theft of iphone with a finger (that happens, I've heard)

Comment: @rsp thumb pitch, yaw, and roll seem less natural than just using my thumb where it naturally rests on the home button and having the notifications be still available after unlocking.  Fortunately, in recent versions of iOS they solved the problem, so it Just Works :)

Answer (score 1):

After reading all the above, I'll try the top button opening trick. 
     Then do a screen shot of the lock screen to save notifications if there are a lot of them. 
   Just tried a screen shot of the lock screen and it works.  I was able to pull it up from the camera roll.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intent on seeing notifications first without accidentally unlocking the phone, just use the top button. That's what I do. I automatically hit that button as I pick up the phone or pull it out of my pocket. Then I hit the home button if I need to go any further.